# ¿Por qué "bacallao" perdió una "l"?

Tags: etimología, historia, animales

La palabra **bacallao** aparece recogida, en textos y diccionarios, antes que **bacalao**.
Por ejemplo, en el Quijote bacallao aparece varias veces, como en el cap. 2, y ninguna "bacalao":

> "... un pescado que ... en Andalucía [llaman] bacallao ...
> ...
> "... trújole el huésped una porción del mal remojado y peor cocido bacallao ... "

o en el [Diccionario de Autoridades](http://web.frl.es/DA.html):

> BACALLAO. s. m. Género de pescado seco y curado al áire, ò al Sol, que fresco es lo mismo que Abadéjo, y salado y curado se llama tambien assi. Llamóse Bacalláo por el País en cuya mar se pesca, que tiene este nombre. Lat. *Asellus. Malva, ae*.

La forma con una sola "l", **bacalao** aparece por primera vez en el Dicionario de la Lengua en 1832, asociado a la foma **bacallao** y se va imponiendo, ya que ediciones posteriores (incluida la actual), la entrada bacallao remite a la entrada bacalao.

¿Por qué "bacallao" perdió una "l" a favor de "bacalao"?

Answer (score 2):

Lo único que encuentro al respecto es en el etimológico de Corominas, y ni siquiera él lo tenía claro:

> [*Bacallao*] es la [forma] general en el Siglo de Oro, en Cervantes, Lope, Ruiz de Alarcón, etc., y la que da aún *Aut[oridades, 1726].* Terr[erros y Pando, 1786] advierte que "algunos sólo pronuncian una *l*"; antes se documenta ya la forma *bacalao* en Percivale (1599), pero forma rara entonces, pues Oudin (1607), Covarr[ubias, 1611] y Franciosini traen unánimemente *bacallao*, y si bien el *DHist.* señala *bacalao* en Lope, en un Arancel de 1782 y en el Duque de Rivas, en estas mismas fuentes se halla, y aun con mayor frecuencia, *bacallao*, de suerte que cabría sospechar modernización de los editores. El origen de la variante con *-l-* no está aclarado. En tiempo de Cervantes se consideraba *bacallao* como andaluz, frente a *abadejo*, propio de Castilla (*Quijote*, I, ii, 6 vº); quizá aquél era general en toda la zona periférica.

Parece que el origen más probable según Corominas (y [según el DLE](https://dle.rae.es/bacalao)) es el vasco *bakailao*, y está emparentado con el neerlandés antiguo *bakeljauw*, variante de *kabeljauw*. Puede que ambas formas convivieran (con *l* y con *ll*) y se pronunciaran de una forma u otra según la región, hasta que una acabó por imponerse, puede que por la forma en que se pronuncia el grupo *il* en *bakailao*, que tiene un sonido lateral palatizado.

Comment: La palabra neerlandesa actual es kabeljauw, bakeljauw se usa en las Antillas holandesas como un plato de bacalao salado. ¿Podrías dar una referencia de bakeljauw como la palabra antigua de bacalao?

Comment: @Leo mi referencia es [el propio DLE](https://dle.rae.es/bacalao), me he limitado a copiar lo que dice la etimología de la palabra, aunque he comprobado que el DLE recoge que _bakeljauw_ es una variante de _kabeljauw_, como indicas, en neerlandés antiguo (ignoro su uso en la actualidad). He modificado la respuesta para añadir ese dato.